# Namespace qualified record field accessors

Tags: clojure, record, keyword

I've made the same dumb mistake many many times:

```
(defrecord Record [field-name])

(let [field (:feld-name (->Record 1))] ; Whoops!
  (+ 1 field))
```

Since I misspelled the field name keyword, this will cause a NPE.

The "obvious" solution to this would be to have `defrecord` emit namespaced keywords instead, since then, especially when working in a different file, the IDE will be able to immediately show what keywords are available as soon as I type `::n/`.

I could probably with some creativity create a macro that wraps `defrecord` that creates the keywords for me, but this seems like overkill.

Is there a way to have `defrecord` emit namespaced field accessors, or is there any other good way to avoid this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because defrecords compile to java classes and fields on a java class don't have a concept of namespaces, I don't think there's a good way to have defrecord emit namespaced keywords.

One alternative, if the code is not performance sensitive and doesn't need to implement any protocols and similar, is to just use maps.

Another is, like Alan Thompson's solution, to make a safe-get funtion. The `prismatic/plumbing` util library also has an implementation of this.

```
(defn safe-get [m k]
  (let [ret (get m k ::not-found)]
    (if (= ::not-found ret)
      (throw (ex-info "Key not found: " {:map m, :key k}))
      ret)))

(defrecord x [foo])

(safe-get (->x 1) :foo) ;=> 1

(safe-get (->x 1) :fo) ;=>

;; 1. Unhandled clojure.lang.ExceptionInfo
;;  Key not found:
;;  {:map {:foo 1}, :key :fo}
```

Answer (score 2):

I feel your pain. Thankfully I have a solution that saves me many times/week that I've been using a couple of years. It is [the `grab` function from the Tupelo library](https://github.com/cloojure/tupelo#map-value-lookup). It does not provide the type of IDE integration you are hoping for, but it does provide *fail-fast* typo-detection, so you **always** be notified the **very first time** you try to use the non-existant key. Another benefit is that you'll get a stacktrace showing the line number with the misspelled keyword, not the line number (possibly far, far away) where the `nil` value causes a NPE.

It also works equally well for both records & plain-old maps (my usual use-case).

From the README:

---

## Map Value Lookup

Maps are convenient, especially when keywords are used as functions to look up a value in a map. Unfortunately, attempting to look up a non-existent keyword in a map will return nil. While sometimes convenient, this means that a simple typo in the keyword name will silently return corrupted data (i.e. nil) instead of the desired value.

Instead, use the function grab for keyword/map lookup:

```
(grab k m)
  "A fail-fast version of keyword/map lookup.  When invoked as (grab :the-key the-map),
   returns the value associated with :the-key as for (clojure.core/get the-map :the-key).
   Throws an Exception if :the-key is not present in the-map."

(def sidekicks {:batman "robin" :clark "lois"})
(grab :batman sidekicks)
;=> "robin"

(grab :spiderman m)
;=> IllegalArgumentException Key not present in map:
map : {:batman "robin", :clark "lois"}
keys: [:spiderman]
```

The function grab should also be used in place of clojure.core/get. Simply reverse the order of arguments to match the "keyword-first, map-second" convention.

For looking up values in nested maps, the function fetch-in replaces clojure.core/get-in:

```
(fetch-in m ks)
  "A fail-fast version of clojure.core/get-in. When invoked as (fetch-in the-map keys-vec),
   returns the value associated with keys-vec as for (clojure.core/get-in the-map keys-vec).
   Throws an Exception if the path keys-vec is not present in the-map."

(def my-map {:a 1 
             :b {:c 3}})
(fetch-in my-map [:b :c])
3
(fetch-in my-map [:b :z])
;=> IllegalArgumentException Key seq not present in map:
;=>   map : {:b {:c 3}, :a 1}
;=>   keys: [:b :z]
```

---

Your other option, using records, is to use the Java-interop style of accessor:

```
(.field-name myrec)
```

Since Clojure `defrecord` compiles into a simple Java class, your IDE *may* be able to recognize these names more easily. YMMV

Comment: Thanks. I'm going to leave this open for a bit though because I was hoping for a solution that doesn't require including a third party.

Comment: Looks like defrecord is not compatible with namespaced keys, so spec/keys can't work with them. Looks like you can have protocols (with defrecords) or "entity maps" from the spec guide, but not both.