# Is it possible to use namespaced keywords with records ?

Tags: clojure

In my app I need an optimization booster.
I noticed that records are significantly faster than maps (probably because record' fields are accessed with native class field access by the JVM)

The map I'm replacing used namespaced keywords as keys

```
(def m {:app.core/k 1 })
```

I'm replacing the definition with

```
(defrecord R [k])
(def m (->R 1))
```

Code is

```
(defn two [m] (assoc m :app.core/k 2))
```

Unfortunately, running this code when m is a record, it assoc a new namespaced key :app.core/k that won't benefit optimization.

Is it possible to declare the record such that it will use namespaced keyword ?

Comment: I wish. I really hoped they'd have records emit namespaced keywords as well as plain vanilla ones in future versions, but I seem to recall reading a post where Rich himself says that it isn't going to happen.

Comment: And if you're in the namespace of the keyword that you want to reference, you can use a double colon: `::k` instead of explicitly writing the namespace.

Comment: @Carcigenicate I tried to find Rich post in mailing list but couldn't find it. I would love to read what he says regarding my question. Maybe what I'm trying to achieve is counter intuitive after all ?

Comment: I'll see if I can find it in a bit.

Comment: Sorry, I was thinking of this: https://dev.clojure.org/jira/browse/CLJ-1938 At the bottom Alex Miller weighs in, not Rich. He is a contributor to the language though.

Comment: Kinda sorta duplicate of my old post: https://stackoverflow.com/q/43789826

Comment: too bad; without them, spec/keys can't work on defrecords, sfaict

Answer (score 2):

There is no such a possibility for this, at least as I know. Only non-qualified names for deftype/defrecord declarations are allowed.

I'm not sure if it will help, but still: you may declare instances of typed records using the standard `#` reader macro prepending any map. So probably you could get rid of the most of constructor functions:

```
(def m #some.ns.YourRecord {:foo 1 :bar 2 :baz 3})
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to Ivan's answer, you can also do this:

```
(defrecord MyRecord [name])
=> user.MyRecord
(def m2 (map->MyRecord {:foo/bar "dan" :other "tom" :name "jen"}))
=> #'user/m2
(type m2)
=> user.MyRecord
m2
=> #user.MyRecord{:name "jen", :foo/bar "dan", :other "tom"}
```

I.e. you can add namespace keys, but not as part of the defined record fields, so the positional constructor is not supported, but `map->MyRecord` constructor works.